# Who should perform shraddha/funeral ceremony of a married women whose husband is still alive

Tags: rituals, death, brahmins, sraddha

According to shastra (specifically to Brahmin, no offence to others though) who should perform funeral and post death rituals of a married women whose husband in still alive (they call muttaide in Kannada language, if anyone is familiar with Kannada)? Is it her husband or the eldest son?

Few people says it should be done by husband as he is the first person to have right on his wife, few people say even eldest son can perform this rights. Is there any mention in our shastras regarding this (excuse my ignorance, if I haven't studied shastras clearly). Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Eldest son has the right to perform the rituals. Putra = who saves from a naraka named Punnama. Husband can do only if there are no sons.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma if parent is alive then son is not supposed to do shraddha right..

Comment: Yes without a doubt. This is called Atma Shraddha. Where a man if better along with his wife does their own shardh. This is mentioned in Ling Puran chapter 45. Atma Shraddha is the most pious act.